# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'John' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to retrieve records base on the keyword which is stored into skw textbox, when I pass USN or Age then it gives correct result but it's not working with Name. It throwing error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorExceptionUnknown
> column 'NAME_KEYWORD(skw)' in 'where clause'

```
ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("select * from Student where USN="+skw.getText()+" or Name='"+skw.getText()+"' or Age="+skw.getText()+"");
```

Comment: Do not concatenate values into a query string. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Instead you should use a prepared statement with parameters, and then set the value for each parameter. The driver will then correctly handle any necessary escaping, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are select for text you should wrap  with single quote the text values

```
ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("select * from Student where USN='"
    +skw.getText()+"' or Name='"+skw.getText()+"' or Age='"+skw.getText()+"'");
```

otherwise the resulting text in used as column name

Comment: It wasn't me, but it's possible you got downvoted for not pointing the questioner towards parameterised SQL.